# Using python, I can't access shared drive folders from Google Drive API v3

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

I can get mydrive folders, but I can't access shared drive folders from Google Drive API.
This is my code.(almost same to the Guides' code [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python))

**I followed the Guides, finished "Enable the Drive API", execute the pip command on VScode, and put credentials.json to the working directory.**

(I got no error, only got filename list of mydrive or 'No files found' that is printed by the code.)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I got no error, only got 'No files found' that is printed by the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that the API has the [`includeItemsFromAllDrives` parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters) in order to determine whether shared drive items show up or not in the results.

The Python API V3 wrapper  also has this parameter included  on it's [list method implementation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.files.html#list) that needs to  be included when calling the `list()` method:

```
...

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

...
```

Comment: Heres another link to some documentation [Implement shared drive support](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives)

Comment: I got this error.
  ~ returned "The supportsAllDrives parameter was not set to true.". Details: "The supportsAllDrives parameter was not set to true.">

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. One quick tip in order to test your API call would be to use the Try this API [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true), build your request as per the relevant parameters to be used in order to see what response you get, and then build your request equivalent with the relevant parameters using the Python's Drive API [list() method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.files.html#list)